# Convert timeseries into daily timeseries graph image in python

Tags: python, time-series

What I have:

1. A minutely time series data of 2 years

What I want:

1. 365*2 = 730 plot/graph images representing daily data

My data looks like this,

```
datetime                 usage
2020-01-01 12:00          10
2020-01-01 12:01          20
.
.
.
  
2021-12-31 11:59          15
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your index is the timeseries, you can resample to day and take the mean:

```
df['Variable_Name_to_plot'].resample('d').mean().plot()
```

Comment: yeah but how do I get daily usage plots, separately?

Comment: @RajatRaja Please add reproducible dataframe and I will update my answer to daily plots.